# MySQL GROUP BY quantity

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

MySQL table is like this (VoteID is PK):

```
VoteID  VoteValue CommentID
1         -1         1
2         -1         1
3          1         1
4         -1         1
5          1         2
6          1         2
7         -1         2
```

I need a result:

```
CommentID    Plus    Minus
    1          1      3 
    2          2      1
```

Sum of "Pluses", Sum of "Minuses" groupped by CommentID
Is it possible to get desired in one SQL expression?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CommentID,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VoteValue > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PLUS,
    SUM(CASE WHEN VoteValue < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MINUS

FROM 
    mytable

GROUP BY 
    CommentID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a query in the lines of:

```
SELECT CommentID,
    SUM(IF(VoteValue > 0, 1, 0)) AS Plus,
    SUM(IF(VoteValue < 0, 1, 0)) AS Minus
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY CommentID
ORDER BY CommentID
```